# Нужно сделать , чтобы данные сайта сохранялись

Tags: javascript, html, css3

```
var numid = document.getElementById('numeric');
var buttonid = document.getElementById('buttork');
var counter = 0;
buttonid.addEventListener('click',function(){
  counter++;
  numid.textContent=''+counter;
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что значит сохранялись? Куда сохранялись?

Comment: Если речь идет о хранение данных в браузере пользователя то самое простое это LocalStorage браузера. Если хранить на ващем сервере то надо писать бэкенд который будет пользоваться какой то базой данных и как то идентифицировать пользователей. Но если все просто и хранить в браузере пользователя то вот годная ссылка [Клац Клац](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage) Если интерессны инные места где можно хранить данные пользователя в его жэ браузере то вот ещё технологии [Клац Клац](https://learn.javascript.ru/data-storage)
На этом сайте всё описано подробно и понятно думаю добавить более неч